# How can I tell what architecture a microprocessor is from the assembled code?

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, machine-code, microprocessors

I have a device I am trying to reverse-engineer. I am trying to avoid opening the physical device up, so I sniffed the packets received while doing a firmware update. However I have no clue what architecture this microprocessor is.

Here's a sample:

`df f8 0c d0 01 f0 06 f8 20 48 20 47 31 15 06 20 f8 f5 03 20 09 4b 1e f0 04 0f 1c bf ef f3 09 80 18 47 ef f3 08 80 06 49 06 4a 88 42 01 d8 90 42 02 d8 8d 46 4f f0 20 20 18 47 20 20 51 77 03 20 f8 f5 03 20 70 e2 03 20 30 b4 50 e8 01 2f 93 b2 c4 89 23 44 84 89 a3 42 28 bf 1b 1b 04 89 a3 42 02 bf bf f3 2f 8f 20 20 07 e0 c3 ea 02 03 40 e8 01 34 20 2c e9 d1 4f f0 01 20 0a 60 30 bc 70 47 50 e8 01 2f c2 ea 02 42 40 e8 01 21 20 29 f7 d1 70 47 30 b4 50 e8 02 2f 1f fa a2 f3 c4 88 a3 42 02 bf bf f3 2f 8f 20 20 0d e0 c4 89 23 44 84 89 a3 42 28 bf 1b 1b c2 ea 03 43 40 e8 02 34 20 2c e8 d1 4f f0 01 20 0a 60 30 bc 70 47 50 e8 02 2f c2 ea 22 42 40 e8 02 21 20 29 f7 d1 70 47 03 46 53 e8 02 2f d9 88 b2 eb 32 4f 4f f0 20 20 17 bf 92 b2 41 ea 01 41 42 ea 01 41 04 e0 5a 68 b2 eb 32 4f 08 bf 01 20 43 e8 02 12 20 2a e8 d1 70 47 30 b4 04 46 54 e8 20 0f 0d 46 44 e8 20 53 20 2b f8 d1 15 60 30 bc 70 47 30 b4 04 46 54 e8 20 0f 40 ea 01 05 44 e8 20 53 20 2b f7 d1 15 60 30 bc`

I have an online disassembler, and am currently trying each architecture I see in the long list (there are a lot). I'm hoping there's an easier way to do this, or if there's any skilled ASM-ers out there that can just recognize the patterns by heart.

Near the end of the long hex dump, there are some references to C code, so whatever it is, there is a compiler out there that supports it.

Also, if this is the wrong community, please let me know and I will move it.

Comment: Note that the firmware update might be compressed and/or encrypted over the wire, but perhaps you have reason to believe this is raw machine code?  If it's part of a TCP stream, it still might not start at an instruction boundary, though.

Comment: It initiated an HTTP download of a zip file. Inside, there's a .bin (what the sample came from), a .dat, and a manifest.json.

Comment: Fortunately it doesn't look encrypted or compressed.  It doesn't look like x86,  Knowing what kind of a device this is supposed to be for might help, as that would help exclude certain CPUs.

Comment: It's this: https://www.umidigi.com/page-umidigi_ufit_specification.html

Comment: FWIW, a very cursory search says “NRF52840 processor” which is a SoC that uses a “32-bit ARM Cortex M-4” — https://www.smartwatchspecifications.com/umidigi-ufit-smartwatch-review-of-features/  , https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Low-power-short-range-wireless/nRF52840

Comment: What did you search to get that?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=umidigi+ufit+processor

Comment: In general (not for this certain device) this is not possible; please also note that there are CPUs that have a co-processor with a different instruction set. For example some TC27x chips (TriCore instruction set) have an XC800 (8051 instruction set) and a Cortex-M3 (ARM Thumb instruction set) co-processor and a Multi-Channel-Sequencer (having its own instruction set). So the code in the memory of the device may be a mix of four different instruction sets.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's ARM Thumb code:

```
   0:   f8df d00c       ldr.w   sp, [pc, #12]   ; 0x10
   4:   f001 f806       bl      0x1014
   8:   4820            ldr     r0, [pc, #128]  ; (0x8c)
   a:   4720            bx      r4
   c:   1531            asrs    r1, r6, #20
   e:   2006            movs    r0, #6
  10:   f5f8 2003                       ; <UNDEFINED> instruction: 0xf5f82003
  14:   4b09            ldr     r3, [pc, #36]   ; (0x3c)
  16:   f01e 0f04       tst.w   lr, #4
  1a:   bf1c            itt     ne
  1c:   f3ef 8009       mrsne   r0, PSP
  20:   4718            bxne    r3
  22:   f3ef 8008       mrs     r0, MSP
  26:   4906            ldr     r1, [pc, #24]   ; (0x40)
  28:   4a06            ldr     r2, [pc, #24]   ; (0x44)
  2a:   4288            cmp     r0, r1
  2c:   d801            bhi.n   0x32
  2e:   4290            cmp     r0, r2
  30:   d802            bhi.n   0x38
  32:   468d            mov     sp, r1
  34:   f04f 2020       mov.w   r0, #536879104  ; 0x20002000
  38:   4718            bx      r3
  3a:   2020            movs    r0, #32
  3c:   7751            strb    r1, [r2, #29]
...
```

The undefined instruction is constant pool data referenced by the instruction at address 0.

I used the following command to disassemble it:

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-objdump -D -b binary -M force-thumb -m arm_any test.bin
```

ARM Cortext-M CPUs, which only execute the ARM Thumb instruction set, are very popular in devices that need a fair bit of computing power, but also need to be very energy efficient.  This makes Thumb a good place to start on a device like this.

Comment: I can't run that command. What packages do I need? I'm on Debian Buster.

Comment: @Nomkid Sorry, I have no idea.  I don't have a Linux computer of my own, I was using one managed by someone else.

Comment: Maybe sudo apt-get -y install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi binutils-arm-linux-gnueabi  will work.  Works on ubuntu and mint which are debian based not sure who initiated those packages

Comment: otherwise, other pre-built arm tools are available and building binutils from sources is pretty easy.

Comment: Now too be fair this was dumb luck squared, or based on some of the comments on what the processor is or might be.  Rarely can you simply look at data and pick out instruction patterns, full sized arm a high percentage of the 32 bit fixed sized instructions starts with 0xE so that is a clue.  But this appears to be thumb2 arm so not only do you need to start disassembling on a 16 bit instruction boundary, but for some instructions you need to get it on the 32 bit boundary to not get lost.  being variable length you cant just start anywhere and disassemble linearly.

Comment: So @RossRidge can confirm or deny but I think this is the exception not the rule.  Normally you would assuming it is code and not compressed/encrypted data, need to try different disassemblers for different targets with different alignments and endianness to maybe get lucky but likely not get lucky.